# How to get path of a file in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to get path of a file and want to add another file at the same directory, for that I am executing following command which is giving me path with filename.

`dir *install*.jar  /b /s`

How can I get just the path of a file, so that I can change directory to that path and create another file?

Comment: is the install.jar located in the same directory?

Comment: no its available in subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
for /f %%G in ('dir *install*.jar /b /s') do CD "%~dpG"
```

- Loops through the result of the `dir` command
- Find the `D`rive and the `P`ath of the matched files
- Change directory to the path found

Note: this even works with multiple files matched. If such situation is encountered, it will change directory to the last matched file. You may want to use the `/o` flag in `dir` to change the order of the list.

Comment: Thanks @SteveFest, this worked, Just had to make small change,`%~dpG`  instead of `%~dpF`